# Cargo install wasm-pack on Windows getting: child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

I'm a beginner trying to install wasm-pack on Windows, but it got stuck on this::

```
Compiling binary-install v0.1.0

1 [main] perl 2393 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2394 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2395 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2396 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2397 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2398 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2399 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2400 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2401 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2402 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

0 [main] perl 2403 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

0 [main] perl 2404 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

0 [main] perl 2405 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2406 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

0 [main] perl 2407 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2408 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2409 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied

1 [main] perl 2410 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Cwd.dll' (0xD0000) is already occupied
```

Any idea what to do ?